# Bootstrap popover plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the [Twitter Bootstrap popover plugin](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers) to bring up a popover when a `<span>` element is clicked.

All the files are including on the page, including `bootstrap-tooltip.js` and `bootstrap-popover.js`. This is my jQuery code to call the popover:

```
$('#supported-hosts').popover({
    'animation': true,
    'html': 'test',
    'trigger': 'click'
});
```

However when I click the element nothing happens. There's no Javascript error in the developer console or anything.

I've also tried doing this to no effect:

```
$('#supported-hosts').on('click', function() {
    $(this).popover('show');
});
```

I'm pretty clueless as to what's wrong because as far as I can tell from the Bootstrap docs I'm using it correctly.

Edit: Also the HTML is simply a span element:

```
<span id="supported-hosts">Supported filehosts</span>
```

Comment: could you also include the HTML you're using in your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show a pop-over, you need to indicate what its content should be.

You can do this on the html tag itself:

```
<span id="supported-hosts" data-content="Popover content">Supported filehosts</span>
```

Or with JavaScript:

```
$('#supported-hosts').popover({
    'content': 'Popover content'
    'animation': true,
    'html': 'test',
    'trigger': 'click'
});
```

By default, the pop-over will use the `title` attribute of the element that triggers it, so you can use that as well, depending on your needs.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking it would just use the default `''` and not show anything. Thanks! :)